# Rotate UIImage and Move

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, ciimage

I have searched stack overflow too many times and also posted a question but in vain. I need to implement a function in my collage app where user can rotate a uiimage and move it as rotated image. Any idea of how to do it? I will try all of them if needed. Am being frustrated searching for it for last two days.

At first i have rotated the frame of the UIImage using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle). It was working but when moving the image after rotation, it was creating distortion. So any other way of doing it?

edit:
to make it clear, 
rotation angle is custom.

Comment: You posted some code for rotating, but how did you move the view ? More code is needed to understand what you did.

Comment: @Maniac One: You have distortion if  rotation angle equal 90*n degrees? If distortion appear only if angle not equal 90*n degrees - you move frame by change origin of frame?

Comment: @A-Live i have shown there how i have moved the view. i have done it by updating the imageView in an array and performing the same 'handlePanGesture' function.

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko Distortion is happening all the time. I am rotating it using UIRotationGestureRecognizer. On rotation everything is fine. When am moving the view after rotation its distorting. Ya am using change of origin of frame :

Comment: @Both, Am I going in a wrong approach? what i need is to rotate a image (by gesture) to custom degree and move it to some other part on the view

Comment: @Maniac One, unfortunately with this amount of "shown" I won't be able to help you.

Comment: @Maniac One: I came across a distortion when picture was moved. It happened with pictures turned through an angle not equal to 90*N degrees. The distortions were, if I moved the image by changing the coordinates of the frame. If I changed the coordinates of the center - there was no distortion.

Comment: Maybe help you it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670750/how-to-resize-the-uiview-when-cgaffinetransformidentity

Comment: @RuslanSoldatenko: Yes i was moving it my changing the co-ordinates of the frame and everytime it was getting auto-resized. I will try with your solution of changing co-ordinates of center and will give you feedback asap. Thanks for helping me so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having examined some of the similar questions ([Change uiview size after rotation transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858513/change-uiview-size-after-rotation-transform) and [How to resize the UIView when CGAffineTransformIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670750/how-to-resize-the-uiview-when-cgaffinetransformidentity)) and read the [Official documentation about CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) I have come to some simple conclusions. Will explain them below.

When you use `CGAffineTransform` for some object with followed  frame transform you must use some rules for obtain correct result:

1. If transform property of object is equal `CGAffineTransformIdentity` you can change frame of object or use `CGAffineTransform` without restriction.
2. If If transform property of object is not equal `CGAffineTransformIdentity` and you want change frame of object without `CGAffineTransform`:
   a) save value of object transform to some local (or another type) variable
   b) set transform property of object to CGAffineTransformIdentity
   c) change frame of object
   d) restore transform value from local (or another type) variable.
3. If transform property of object is not equal `CGAffineTransformIdentity` and you want use `CGAffineTransform`, for example `new_transform`:
   a) use `CGAffineTransformConcat([object transform] , new_transform)` to obtain `result_transform`
   b) set transform value of object to `result_transform`

Compliance with these simple rules will help avoid many problems.

Note: you must remember, when you use `CGAffineTransformConcat`  all transform totalized. For example: if you want rotate object from 6 degree to 7 degree, you must add transform rotate to 1 degree, not to 7. Otherwise you obtain rotation 6 + 7 = 13 degree.

Comment: This explanation really helped me a lot. I will Follow this and post my result output here. Thanks for helping me in my difficult situation. am stuck with it for last 2 days and was approaching with CIContext which was getting much more complex

Comment: This gave me some lead but I am still not convinced if this is the optimal approach to update the size of a `UIView` with non-identity `CGAffineTransform`

Answer (score 1):

For anyOne who may migrate here may find this part of the Code useful:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
imageToBeMoved.center = CGPointMake(primaryTapPoint.x   ,primaryTapPoint.y); 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Changing: imageToBeMoved.frame to imageToBeMoved.center solves the problem