# Update Frame of Rotated UIView

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to update the size of rotated `UIView`. I tried using `CGAffineTransform` for rotation but whenever I tried updating the size after rotation it messed up the frame.

I somehow managed to update size of rotated view using this [stackoverflow answer: rotate-uiimage-and-move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837512/rotate-uiimage-and-move/19862637#19862637) which suggests:

1. Preserving original transform and assigning `.identity` to the view's transform
2. Updating frame of view
3. Reassign original transform

Here is my final code which is working perfectly:

```
    func handlePinch(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        // Preserve previous transform and assign .identity
        let transform = myView.transform
        myView.transform = .identity

        // Compute new frame
        let updatedOrigin = myView.frame.origin.applying(transform.scaledBy(x: gesture.scale, y: gesture.scale))
        let updatedSize = CGSize(width: myView.frame.width * gesture.scale, height: myView.frame.height * gesture.scale)
        myView.bounds = CGRect(origin: updatedOrigin, size: updatedSize)

        // Assign back original transform
        textView.transform = transform

        gesture.scale = 1

    }
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this the right approach to do that? To me it seems like a hack as transform using frame's origin to compute new origin which only works fine when assigned to bounds origin.
2. What is the best way to achieve resizing a rotated view?

Comment: When you say `whenever I tried updating the size after rotation it messed up the frame` - how were you increasing the size ? The steps 1-2-3 you mention does not seem like a hack to me because if you want to to rotate and increase the size, these are both **transforms** - scaling & rotating. The order of transformation is important: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/4194

Comment: I was updating the size using similar logic as I mentioned except for changing the transform back to identity and reassignment.

Comment: same issue. searching for solution. - @Amir

Comment: I wasn't able to get the rotated frame size however above mention approach works well @AsimIftikharAbbasi